# Delete iframes with broken link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this kind of problem, I have iframes with videos embedded into my pages of the website. Note, that iframes urls are from **another domain**. From time to time these urls can be broken, or stop working and instead of the video there is a message "This video has been removed from public access. ". Is there any way that I can delete those "failed" iframes from the pages by jquery or just javascript.

I was thinking I could be able to search for text inside iframes similar t

```
$("iframe").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).is(':contains("video has been")');
    console.log(val); // returns false
});
```

and then remove those, but it returns false, afa I understood from the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

Also, if it matters, I found out that the difference(without having the above text) between working and broken iframe, is that the last one does not contain `object` node.

Is there any method to handle this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: You can do a cross-domain `GET` request to the specific address to see if it contains `"video has been"`.

Comment: Here's how to bypass Same Origin Policy: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/HGHJ5/

Comment: Thanks @Derek朕會功夫 for the reply, I was trying the CD ajax, but got some errors, lemme try the jsfiddle code and will let u know. tks

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, thanks man a lot, that solved the problem. u saved my day :). lets post it as an unswer and accept that, maybe it will save someone's time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Same Origin Policy, the browser will prevent all AJAX to different domains and direct access of `iframe`s of different domain. However, there are ways to bypass this limit. One way is to let a server to fetch the data, then return back the data to the client. [Here](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) is one plugin for jQuery that does this. It uses YQL (Yahoo Query Language) as a proxy.

Just make a normal GET request with `.ajax` and the plugin will handle of the details for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: [url of the iframe],
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        $(data.responseText);  //do something with it
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/HGHJ5/

Of course, if you don't trust Yahoo of handling the data, you can always host one yourself.